# What are epub JSON links?

Tags: epub

I've spotted that there are some links within the epub using a format in line with JSON

```
<a href="{&quot;unit&quot;: &quot;U01&quot;, &quot;page&quot;: 24, &quot;exercise&quot;: [&quot;AB1&quot;]}">
```

the href look like this

```
{"unit": "U01", "page": 24, "exercise": ["AB1"]}
```

What are those links? are they described in the epub-3 specification? and how does the reader handle that kind of JSON href references?

Comment: Which site was the file published on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reader should just ignore it.

According to epub standard which says content should be valid XHTML or HTML5 and then  following the links through to the [RFC 3987](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) for an URI section 2.2 a href begins with a scheme (e.g. http) and then a :

I would guess that there is a reader that preprocesses a file and this converts the JSON to a link.